# How to copy a directory recursively using hardlinks for each file

Tags: files, cp, recursive, hard-link

I want to create a "copy" of a directory tree where each file is a hardlink to the original file

Example: I have a directory structure:

```
dirA/
dirA/file1
dirA/x/
dirA/x/file2
dirA/y/
dirA/y/file3
```

Here is the expected result, a "copy" of the directory tree where each file is a hardlink to the original file:

```
dirB/            #  normal directory
dirB/file1       #  hardlink to dirA/file1
dirB/x/          #  normal directory
dirB/x/file2     #  hardlink to dirA/x/file2
dirB/y/          #  normal directory
dirB/y/file3     #  hardlink to dirA/y/file3
```

Answer (score 103):

On Linux (more precisely with the GNU and `busybox` implementations of `cp` as typically found on systems that have Linux as a kernel) and recent FreeBSD, this is how:

```
cp -al dirA dirB
```

For a more portable solution, see answer using pax and cpio by Stéphane Chazelas

Comment: Note that like `pax`, on FreeBSD, `cp -a` doesn't hardlink symlinks.

Comment: Be aware that hard links do not work across separate filesystem mounts.

Comment: If dirB exists, dirB will CONTAIN the new dirA. If dirB does not exist, dirB will BE the new dirA. But it probably depends on your OS as to the exact behavior.

Comment: `-a` = `--archive` = "same as `-dR --preserve=all`" = "never follow symbolic links in SOURCE", `--preserve=links`, and "copy directories recursively", while `-l` means "hard link files instead of copying"

Comment: In this mode, files won't be overwritten though. Is there a way?

Comment: If you want to preserve the dir structure starting from the current dir/start of the copy path, use `--parents`. Useful when you want to back up some files deep down into the file tree, and want to recover by simply copy paste everything

Answer (score 32):

POSIXly, you'd use `pax` in read+write mode with the `-l` option:

```
pax -rwlpe -s /A/B/ dirA .
```

(`-pe` preserves all possible attributes of files (in this case only directories) that are copied, like GNU `cp`'s `-a` does).

Now, though *standard*, that command is not necessarily very *portable*.

First, many GNU/Linux-based systems don't include `pax` by default (even though that's a non-optional POSIX utility).

Then, a number of bugs and non-conformances with a few implementations cause a number of issues with that code.

- because of a bug, Solaris 10 `pax` (at least) doesn't work when using `-rwl` in combination with `-s`. For some reason, it seems it applies the substitution to both the original and copied path. So above, it would attempt to do some `link("dirB/file", "dirB/file")` instead of `link("dirA/file", "dirB/file")`.
- on FreeBSD, `pax` doesn't create hardlinks for files of type *symlink* (a behaviour allowed by POSIX). Not only that, but it also applies the substitution to the targets of the symlinks (a behaviour *not* allowed by POSIX). So for instance if there's a `foo -> AA` symlink in `dirA`, it will become `foo -> BA` in `dirB`.

Also, if you want to do the same but with arbitrary file paths whose content is stored in `$src` and `$dst`, it's important to realise that `pax -rwl -- "$src" "$dst"` creates the full directory structure of `$src` inside `$dst` (that has to exist and be a directory). For instance, if `$src` is `foo/bar`, then, `$dst/foo/bar` is created.

If instead, you want `$dst` to be a copy of `$src`, the easiest is probably to do it as:

```
absolute_dst=$(umask 077 && mkdir -p -- "$dst" && cd -P -- "$dst" && pwd -P) &&
(cd -P -- "$src" && pax -rwlpe . "$absolute_dst")
```

(which would also work around most of the problems mentioned above but would fail if the absolute path of `$dst` ends in newline characters).

Now that won't help on GNU/Linux systems where there's no `pax`.

It's interesting to note that `pax` was created by POSIX to merge the features of the `tar` and `cpio` commands.

`cpio` is a *historical* Unix command (from 1977) as opposed to a POSIX invention, and there is a GNU implementation as well (not a `pax` one). So even though it is no longer a *standard* command (it was in SUSv2 though), it is still very common, and there's a core set of features you can usually rely on.

The equivalent of `pax -rwl` would be `cpio -pl`. However:

1. `cpio` takes the list of input file on stdin as opposed to arguments (newline delimited which means file names with newline characters are not supported)
2. All files have to be specified (typically you feed it the output of `find` (`find` and `cpio` were developed jointly by the same people)).
3. metadata are not preserved (some `cpio` implementations have options to preserve some, but nothing portable).

So with `cpio`:

```
absolute_dst=$(umask 077 && mkdir -p -- "$dst" && cd -P -- "$dst" && pwd -P) &&
(cd -P -- "$src" && find . | cpio -pl "$absolute_dst")
```

Comment: Seems that -s/A/B/ is specific to my example. How would you do this if the source directory name and target directory name were variables $sourcedir and $targetdir?

Comment: @GudmundurOrn, see edit.

Comment: I run this command on OS X and just receives an error message "pax: Unable to link file ./a.txt to itself". I used the your command literally, just replacing the source directory with the actual name, leaving /A/B and the final dot as is. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @d-b, `-s /A/B` replaces `A` with `B` so that `dirA` becomes `dirB`. If your source directory name has no `A`, then that will copy (link) it over itself. See also the rest of the answer for possibly better approaches.

Answer (score 10):

Short answer:

```
cd $source_folder
pax -rwlpe . $dest_folder
```

Comment: Note that the `pe` toggles can cause privilege issues (Operation not permitted) because ` pax` is calling `chown`. For my use case having hardlinks attributed to the executing user was fine so I ended up using simply `pax -rwl`

Comment: Another issue I encountered is with permissions. If you have a directory owned by `root` and try to create hard links with `pax` using a standard user (e.g. your web server user like `www-data`), the behavior of `pax` is creating copies of the files instead of hardlinks. This is certainly for security reasons (this would allow a user to modify root's files), but be sure to be aware of this.

Answer (score 6):

`rsync -av --link-dest="$PWD/dirA" dirA/ dirB`

If you happen to have `rsync` already installed this one is a quick simple command. To cope with symlinks you may want to choose among `--links, --copy-links, --copy-unsafe-links` or `--safe-links`

From the rsync man page:

```
--link-dest=DIR         hardlink to files in DIR when unchanged
 -l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
 -L, --copy-links            transform symlink into referent file/dir
--copy-unsafe-links     only "unsafe" symlinks are transformed
--safe-links            ignore symlinks that point outside the tree
```

**Edit:**

- Fixed the command after the comment by @MichaelR. Thank you!
- Tested as follows on MacOS using rsync 2.6.9

```
$ cd /tmp && rm -rf a b; mkdir a && touch a/c && echo "xxx" > a/c && rsync -av --link-dest="$PWD/a" a/ b; 
$ ls -lR a b
building file list ... done
created directory b
./

sent 74 bytes  received 26 bytes  200.00 bytes/sec
total size is 4  speedup is 0.04
a:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  2 user  wheel  4 Aug 26 16:09 c

b:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  2 user  wheel  4 Aug 26 16:09 c
```

Comment: `--link-dest` doesn't appear to work for me using rsync v2.6.9 on macOS. I'm running `rsync -av --link-dest=a a/ b/` and directory b/ contains file copies, not hardlinks.

Comment: @MichaelR, you are right. I'm sorry! I tested the following on MacOS and it works: `rsync -av --link-dest="$PWD/a" a/ b`

Answer (score 2):

In case you are looking for that *copy-with-hardlinks* feature to make snapshots or backups of (all or part of) your files have a look at `rsnapshot`.

Comment: That's interesting. But I guess hard-links are only a good snapshot mechanism if the files will not be modified. Right?

Comment: @Gudmundur Orn; This is correct. The tool mentioned in my answer will create a new snapshot in a way that files are unique; i.e. existing (unmodified) files will be created as hardlinks and new files (or modified versions of existing files) will be created as new files. So in consequence you will have the least redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

@gudmundur-orn's answer is correct, but if you are on BtrFS on Linux `cp a --reflink=auto dirA dirB` should do the trick, with the difference the files are actually different and changing one doesn't change the other. You can achieve mostly the same with `cp -c` on a Mac with APFS (`auto` will do a full copy if not possible, `-c` will fail).

Any COW file system should be able to do that, but vendors haven't agreed on a standard command line option.

Comment: You mean `cp -a`?